# Displaying confirm message based on different conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two radio buttons, true or false. And on submit they is a confirm message depending on from true to false, or false to true. Currently I have this.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
 <table>
    <tr>
     <td>User Fee?</td>
     <td><%= radio_button("user", "need_subscription", "true", class: "subscription_button") %>
         <%= radio_button("user", "need_subscription", "false", class: "cancel_subscription_button") %>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Set your fee</td>
     <td><%= f.number_field :fee  %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <div class="margin-top-10">
     <% if current_user.need_subscription?  %>
        <%= f.submit "Save", data: { confirm: 'foo' } %>
     <% else %>
         <%= f.submit "Save", data: { confirm: 'bar' } %>
     <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

What I am having is showing the message 'foo' when user need subscription, but what I want is showing the message 'foo' when user select the `true` radio button and submit. I think there is something to do with `if params select/changed?`. Thanks for help.

Comment: What type is the `need_subscription` attribute on your user model?

Comment: Boolean type. Thanks

Comment: for this you have to write JavaScript on submit event, in which you should check the value of radio button and then show message that you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional will be evaluated when the view is rendered, not based on the selection made while filling out the form. If you want to change the confirmation in real time, you'll probably want to add some (unobtrusive) javascript that determines which message to use when the user selects the appropriate radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Like BM5k noted, the conditional will be evaluated when the view is rendered. For your conditional to do what you expect, your user will have to load up the view first, change the selection of the radio button and submit the form. Then, your `registration_path(resource_name)` action will need to render this view again for the conditional to get re-evaluated with the value your user just submitted.

This may or may not be the behavior you expect. Like BM5k mentioned, you may want to use some Javascript to update the form on the client side as the user changes the selections.

If the former behavior is what you expect, try using the form builder to render the radio button instead of the view helper, like so:

```
<%= f.radio_button :need_subscription, true, class: "subscription_button" %>
```